# Angular calling a function

Tags: angular

In my angular project, I have the following:

**main.html:**

```
   <my_project [Number]="ID"></my_project>
```

**my_project.ts:**

```
export class my_project {
   @Input() Number: Array<any>; 

   ...

   my_function(id){
      console.log("ID number: " +  id);
   };

}
```

I know how to pass data to another directive. I was wondering if there is a way to call a function directly from "main.html" or "main.ts" like below:

```
<my_project [my_function]></my_project>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: why dont you place your method inside ngOnInit it will fire automatically on load ?

Comment: I should have clarified that this is being called multiple times and ngOnInit only fires once initially. Since I need to call "<my_project>" multiple times, I am looking for a way to call a function.

Comment: you need to clarify when you wish this function to be called. Otherwise we have no change of helping

Comment: you can make use of setters in Input and in that setter call that function this might help you call it multiple times when you set the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
<my_project [my_function]="[this, 'this.name = 1; this.sampleFun()']"></my_project>
```

Create directive for calling a function

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[my_function]',
    inputs: ['my_function']
})

export class NgInitDirective {
    my_function;

    ngOnChanges() {
        if (this.my_function) {
            let iife = function(str) { return eval(str); }.call(this.my_function[0], this.my_function[1]);
        }
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    sampleFun() {
        console.log('hello word');
    }
}
```

**module.ts**

```
import {
    AppComponent,
    NgInitDirective
} from './';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NgInitDirective
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple  times mean what exactly.
1) from same component in multiple way,
2) On route load you need to call.
3) from Different different component you want to interact.

There is option in every case please be specific.